# How to select the top 5 as of a certain date in R?

Tags: r

If I have the following data:

```
obs District    ZoneID  Period  SUM_activity
1   Northwestern    Northern: 53A   2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06 4
2   Northwestern    Northern: 53B   2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06 0
3   Northwestern    Northwestern: 61A   2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06 88
4   Northwestern    Northwestern: 61B   2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06 44
5   Northwestern    Northwestern: 61D   2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06 212
6   Northwestern    Northwestern: 62A   2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06 38
7   Northwestern    Northwestern: 62B   2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06 18
8   Northwestern    Northwestern: 62C   2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06 65
9   Northwestern    Northwestern: 62D   2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06 4
10  Northwestern    Northwestern: 63A   2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06 107
11  Northwestern    Northwestern: 63B   2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06 19
12  Northwestern    Northwestern: 63C   2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06 56
13  Northwestern    Northwestern: 63D   2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06 165
14  Northwestern    Northwestern: DATA  2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06 28
15  Northwestern    Northwestern: DATB  2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06 26
16  Northwestern    Northwestern: DATC  2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06 114
17  Northwestern    Outside Zones 2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06   1501
18  Southern    Outside Zones 2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06   2062
19  Southwestern Outside Zones  2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06 1351
```

And I group that data so that it looks like the following:

```
District    2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06
Northwestern    2489
Northern: 53A   4
Northern: 53B   0
Northwestern: 61A   88
Northwestern: 61B   44
Northwestern: 61D   212
Northwestern: 62A   38
Northwestern: 62B   18
Northwestern: 62C   65
Northwestern: 62D   4
Northwestern: 63A   107
Northwestern: 63B   19
Northwestern: 63C   56
Northwestern: 63D   165
Northwestern: DATA  28
Northwestern: DATB  26
Northwestern: DATC  114
Outside Zones 1501
Southern    2062
Outside Zones 2062
Southwestern    1351
Outside Zones 1351
```

Per district, how would I make a table that had three groups:
-the sum of activity for the top 5 zones in terms of sum_activity
-The sum of activity for the remaining zones (basically != Outside Zone and != top 5 category)
-The sum of the outside zone category

These three groups would have to be established based on the sum up to a given period (2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06) assuming that there will be more date ranges than what is in this table, both before and after 2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06.

Here is an example for just the Northwestern District:

```
District    Top 5   Rest of Zones   Outside Zones
Northwestern    686 302 1501
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Given your expected output, it seems you want to calculate the _sum_ of the `SUM_activity` variable for all `ZoneID` (excluding "Not in Zone") that are in the top 5 (according to `SUM_activity`), and then do the same for all `ZoneID` that are not in the top 5, and then again for "Not in Zone". And you want to do all that for each `Period`?  It would be MUCH better if your expected output matched the sample data provided. As it stands, it doesn't, so it's hard to know exactly what you want.

Comment: Yes that is correct. I am trying to calculate, by district, the sum of sum_activity for all the zoneIDs, as of a given Period. Then from there, I am trying to split the sums into three categories: Top 5 ZoneIDs, The rest of the ZoneID, and ZoneID = Not in Zone. Thanks and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Edward I have made the suggested changes you asked. I hope this is more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using `top_n` may work well, getting the "rest" may be difficult, especially if there are ties. In this case, I've created a grouping variable (`grp`) equal to 1 if the `SUM_activity` variable is in the top 5 and 0 otherwise. Then I combined this with those that have ZonedID = "Outside Zones" to create 3 groups.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  mutate(Zone=ifelse(ZoneID=="Outside Zones", 1, 0)) %>%
  group_by(District, Period, Zone) %>%
  mutate(grp=factor(+(min_rank(desc(SUM_activity))<=5) + Zone,
    labels=c("Top 5", "Rest of Zones", "Outside Zones"),
    levels=c(1,0,2))) %>%
  group_by(District, Period, grp) %>%
  summarise(n=sum(SUM_activity)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=grp, values_from=n, values_fill=list(n=0))
```

---

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   District, Period [3]
  District     Period                  `Top 5` `Rest of Zones` `Outside Zones`
  <chr>        <chr>                     <int>           <int>           <int>
1 Northwestern 2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06     686             302            1501
2 Southern     2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06       0               0            2062
3 Southwestern 2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06       0               0            1351
```

---

**Data**

```
data <- structure(list(obs = 1:19, District = c("Northwestern", "Northwestern", 
"Northwestern", "Northwestern", "Northwestern", "Northwestern", 
"Northwestern", "Northwestern", "Northwestern", "Northwestern", 
"Northwestern", "Northwestern", "Northwestern", "Northwestern", 
"Northwestern", "Northwestern", "Northwestern", "Southern", "Southwestern"
), ZoneID = c("Northern: 53A", "Northern: 53B", "Northwestern: 61A", 
"Northwestern: 61B", "Northwestern: 61D", "Northwestern: 62A", 
"Northwestern: 62B", "Northwestern: 62C", "Northwestern: 62D", 
"Northwestern: 63A", "Northwestern: 63B", "Northwestern: 63C", 
"Northwestern: 63D", "Northwestern: DATA", "Northwestern: DATB", 
"Northwestern: DATC", "Outside Zones", "Outside Zones", "Outside Zones"
), Period = c("2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06", "2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06", 
"2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06", "2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06", "2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06", 
"2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06", "2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06", "2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06", 
"2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06", "2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06", "2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06", 
"2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06", "2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06", "2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06", 
"2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06", "2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06", "2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06", 
"2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06", "2019-02-06 - 2019-03-06"), SUM_activity = c(4L, 
0L, 88L, 44L, 212L, 38L, 18L, 65L, 4L, 107L, 19L, 56L, 165L, 
28L, 26L, 114L, 1501L, 2062L, 1351L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))
```

Comment: Thank you @Edward. Now, how would you output a list of the top 5 ZoneID by district (so that I had a list of those zones in each district to apply elsewhere)?

Comment: Thank you @Edward. Now, how would you output a list of the top 5 ZoneID by district (so that I had a list of those zones in each district to apply elsewhere)?
Basically - I have another dataset, but instead of activity, it has SUMevent - but it is laid out the exact same. However I want to use the top 5 criteria here and apply it to the other dataset, so that the SUMevents are based on the ZoneIDs with the top 5 sumActivities. Does that make sense?

Comment: I asked the question in full here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61068264/applying-the-top-5-criterion-created-in-one-dataset-to-operations-in-a-similar-d

Comment: Did my code help to answer your current question? Please don't ask follow-up questions before accepting or voting on current answers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Sorry, did not see that option! Yes your answer pretty much answered it, apart from the section where I wanted the top 5 criteria to be based on the top ZoneIDs AS OF a certain date.

Comment: I see. But your example data only included one date range. And it wasn't clear to me what you meant by "... up to a given period", but I should have clarified that. I'll look at your new question now...

Answer (score -1):

We can use `top_n`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(District, Period) %>%
     top_n(5, wt = SUM_activity)
```

Comment: Thank you! Now how would I pull out the rest of the zones, summed up, and the not in zone category, summed up?